# Subclassing UINavigationBar in Xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationbar, subclassing

I want to apply a custom alpha value to the title of the `UINavigationBar`. The `UINavigationBar` is part of the `UINavigationController` and the `UINavigationController` is part of a `UITabBarController`.

**Edit:** Here is a picture of what I created using a UIToolbar and a UILabel. I want to do the same using the title in the UINavigationController: https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8YX0.png

I think the only way to accomplish this would be to subclass the `UINavigationBar` and override a method that allows me to set the Alpha when it's drawn.

**Here are my questions:**

1. Is this the correct way to do this?
2. What are the HIG ramifications of this?
3. I am new to subclassing in Objective-C, can you provide a guide or
   tutorial that will help me grasp the steps required in subclassing a
   UI Element and implementing a change?
4. When I get the subclass configured, I can view it in IB by changing
   the class of the `UINavigationBar` to my custom class, correct?
5. Are there any "gotchas" that can come up with sublassing that an
   expert like yourself can give me a head's up on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is something you shouldn't do. Why would you want to change that color but not the overall opacity of the bar? it decreases readability. There are multiple problems:

- there is no public API, so it's not trivial
- tampering with the subviews is fragile, may break and may have side-effects
- it's not foreseen to be done -- the alpha value of the view is used and *animated* when pushing/popping a controller

If you really want to do it, there's only one clean, public way: Give each navigation item to be pushed a custom title view. You can tamper with that one as much as you want. So it's possible to set a view with a `UILabel` as subview and having it's alpha set to 0.5.

Answer (score 0):

When a navigation bar is being managed by a navigation controller, there are only a few properties you're allowed to change (see [docs](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationController/navigationBar)).  One of them is `translucent` which adjusts the alpha, but only to an Apple-determined value.

Comment: I'm not wanting to modify the translucent property of the NavigationBar itself, rather the title label contained within. Can I modify, via translucent, the alpha of the title? I added a link to the post to a photo of what I'm trying to accomplish.