# iOS 7 Changing UINavigationBar titleView alpha

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios7, uinavigationbar

So I am using the UINavigationBar component of iOS7, but not the UINavigationController itself. When I push a new view with my custom navigation controller, I want to change the title's alpha to 0.0 and then back, but I can't seem to get it work.

I am trying to do this

```
vc1.navBar.topItem.titleView.alpha = 0.1;
```

It doesn't seem to have any effect. Am I missing something here, is there a correct way to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how I would do it:

- In `viewWillAppear:` of the pushed viewController, I would set it the alpha to 0 using:

  ```
  [self.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                              [[UIColor whiteColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0],
                                                              NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                                                              [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:16.0],
                                                              NSFontAttributeName,
                                                               nil]];
  ```
- In `viewDidAppear:`, set it's alpha back to 1. Here you don't really need to set it's alpha to 1, just setting it to plain `[UIColor whiteColor]` will do the trick.

One other thing you could do is, toggle `HIDDEN` property in the 2 methods.

Setting the alpha of the titleView did not work in my case so I used the above code. It hides the title. In case you want a similar effect with the back button, you set the alpha of the backButton using `self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.customView.alpha =`

Comment: What if I use custom titleView ?

Comment: Then you set the alpha of the custom view

Answer (score 5):

You can set the `titleView` `hidden` in `viewWillAppear`

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    self.navigationItem.titleView.hidden = YES;
}
```

You can't set the `titleView` `alpha` until `viewDidAppear`

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    self.navigationItem.titleView.alpha = 0.5f;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one -

```
[self.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                                    [UIColor colorWithRed:125/255.0 green:178/255.0 blue:15/255.0 alpha:0.2],
                                                                    NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                                                                    [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:16.0],
                                                                    NSFontAttributeName,
                                                                     nil]];
```

If you just want to change the title attributes. Or this one to change bar alpha :

```
[self.navigationBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:125/255.0 green:178/255.0 blue:15/255.0 alpha:0.2]];
```

Comment: Is there a way to animate the alpha change?